# jQuery Calender - More than one event per day

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a calendar on my site that uses javascript/jquery to place events in the calendar. All the events are stored in a MySQL database with the title and Unix timestamp.

My problem is that this method (shown in the code below) only allows one event per day, and creating two rows with the same date, only uses the latter of the two. There are several instances where I need two or more events in one day.

My code:

```
 var CalendarEvent = function (time, title) {
    this.time = time;
    this.title = title;
}

var allEvents = {


    <?php require_once 'ndx/mysql.php';

            $events = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM events");

            while($lse = mysqli_fetch_array($events)): 
            $date = date('Y-m-d', $lse['timestamp']);
            $notime = $lse['notime'];

            if($notime != 'true'){
            $time = date('g:i a', $lse['timestamp']);
            }else{
            $time = '';
            }
            $event = addslashes($lse['title']);
            ?>

    '<?php echo $date; ?>': [
        new CalendarEvent('<?php echo $time; ?>', '<?php echo $event; ?>')
    ],

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I am just thinking you might have a composite key in database table which by definition sets date field as unique. So when you put a new field in it updates the existing date event with its title and you get last one. Paste your database scheme for this table only with primary and unique keys

Comment: you need to restructure your data output so keys of the javascript object aren't duplicated